# Are two equivalent coverings of a Riemann surface also biholomorphic?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

Consider a compact Riemann surface $X$. If $p_1:Y\longrightarrow X $ and $p_2:Z\longrightarrow X$ are two topological coverings of $X$, then it is univocally defined a structure of Riemann surface on both $Y$ and $Z$ such that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are holomorphic. Now if these two coverings are equivalent, then there is a homeomorphism
$g: Y\longrightarrow Z$ such that $p_2\circ g=p_1$, but **is $g$ a biholomorphism**? In other terms two equivalent coverings of a compact Riemann surfaces are isomorphic in the category of Riemann surfaces?

I think that the answer is yes because in classical complex analysis if $g$ and $f$ are two holomorphic functions with $g$ non costant and moreover if  $F$ is a continuous function such that $g\circ F=f$, then $F$ is holomorphic. I can't formalize this argument in the case of Riemann surfaces.

Comment: You just need to verify that the homeomorphism is locally holomorphic (and the same for its inverse).

Comment: And since the coverings are local biholomorphisms, that isn't hard.

Comment: Yes, I had  missed the local biholomorphism of the coverings. Many thanks

Comment: Being holomorphic is a local property. Everything that is a local property works the same for Riemann surfaces as in classical complex analysis; just pick convenient local charts and do things as usual.